# could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

My Domain Class is as below. Primary key Id is combination of 2 fields serviceProviderId and sportsId (which are present in another table serviceProvider and Sports respectively). When I start my grails app, i get the below exception

org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.zonalde.FieldsDetails column: service_provider_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

What am I probably missing here. I already had tables in place and generated domain classes using [Database Reverse Engineering Plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-db-reverse-engineer/docs/manual/guide/single.html)

Please help

```
class FieldsDetails implements Serializable {

    Integer serviceProviderId
    Integer sportsId
    String isPaynPlay
    Boolean isActive
    Sports sports
    ServiceProvider serviceProvider

    int hashCode() {
        def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
        builder.append serviceProviderId
        builder.append sportsId
        builder.toHashCode()
    }

    boolean equals(other) {
        if (other == null) return false
        def builder = new EqualsBuilder()
        builder.append serviceProviderId, other.serviceProviderId
        builder.append sportsId, other.sportsId
        builder.isEquals()
    }

    static belongsTo = [ServiceProvider, Sports]

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ["serviceProviderId", "sportsId"]
        version false

    }

    static constraints = {

        isPaynPlay nullable: true, maxSize: 1
        isActive nullable: true

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your mappings as :

```
static mapping = {
        id composite: ["serviceProviderId", "sportsId"]
        version false
        serviceProvider column: '`service_provider_id`', insertable: false, updateable: false
        sports column: '`sports_id`', insertable: false, updateable: false
    }
```

You can refer grails doc for more details [here](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.1.0/ref/Database%20Mapping/updateable.html)

Comment: Thanks @Rahul, but after your change i got the below error will starting the grails app

Comment: @SandeepPoonia i have the updated the code and error in the question description. Now it fails with a different error

Comment: Difficult to determine the exact issue from one liner. Can you add more description i.e Exception logs

Comment: @VinodJayachandran What's the new error that you are getting?